# why cumsum is not computing correctly when using dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table such as given below:

```
Days
0
20
0
657
80
0
151
34
119
63
30
32
57
0
156
208
369
122
0
153
57
279
208
427
0
462
63
0
16
158
```

I want to compute CumSum using dplyr in R and this is what I am using:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(CummDays = ifelse(Days==0, 0, cumsum(Days)))
```

What I am getting as result is valid for a few rows and then there is error as shown in the below table. Here after 14th Row, the cumsum should be reset to start counting from ZERO and it is not the case. :

```
Days    CummDays
0       0
20      20
0       0
657     657
80      737
0       0
151     151
34      185
119     304
63      367
30      397
32      429
57      486
0       0
156     642    <- Here is the error
208     850
369     1219
122     1341
0       0
153     153
57      210
279     489
208     697
427     1124
0       0
462     462
63      525
0       0
16      541     <- Here is another error
158     699
```

What I want should be something like this as shown below, I am not sure why the above function is not correctly computing:

```
Days    CummDays
0       0
20      20
0       0
657     657
80      737
0       0
151     151
34      185
119     304
63      367
30      397
32      429
57      486
0       0
156     156
208     364
369     733
122     855
0       0
153     153
57      210
279     489
208     697
427     1124
0       0
462     462
63      525
0       0
16      16
158     174
```

Comment: You need to `group_by(grp = cumsum(Days == 0))`, i.e. `df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(Days == 0)) %>% mutate(new = cumsum(Days))`

Comment: You need to create a grouping variable to group your data between the zeros and then calculate the cumsum of each group. Try the code I provided and it will get clearer

Comment: yes it worked. only thing was there, I need to do a step before. `df <- as.data.frame(df)`

Comment: Well yes... I thought it was since you name it `df` (**d**ata **f**rame)